# Data Excel loses and wrong formats when data is copied from ADODB recordset

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

After using ADODB recordset to paste data in Excel, some columns have lost data and some have the wrong format as below.

[image]

```
                If SheetExists(conn, sheetName) Then
                    ' Create a recordset for the sheet
                    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]", conn, 3, 1
                    
                    ' Copy data from the recordset to the new workbook
                    Dim destWs As Worksheet
                    Set destWs = destWb.Sheets.Add
                    'sheetname
                    leng = Len(sheetName) - 1
                    destWs.Name = Left(sheetName, leng)
                    'Copy header
                    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
                        destWs.Cells(1, i).Value = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
                    Next i
                    'copy Data
                    If Not rs.EOF Then
                    destWs.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
                    End If
                    ' Close the recordset
                    rs.Close
                End If
```

I want the output to have the same format and correct data.

Comment: You are probably out of luck. ADO doesn't cope well with mixed data types in a column. Best you can really do is to add IMEX=1 to your connection string if you don't already have it. As for the number formats, they are down to the cell formats, not the recordset.

Comment: Yes, I have IMEX=1
How solve this case?  @Rory

Comment: Either don't use ADO (eg use power query instead) or clean up the data so that the data types are consistent within a column.

Comment: Are those cells with lost data also empty if you'd [fill an array with the recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408217/19353309)?